# how to dynamically populate javascript data structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

when an user click on my display link, it goes to my display page, a javascript runs after the page load and render the display.  something like below: 

`...
display_data_hash = {}`

function display() {
   // use display_data_hash here
}
...

is it possible to populate "display_data_hash" in my javascript on the server side?  or should i just add  tag to my view and populate display_data_hash inside my html.  i really don't want mix javascript with html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach using AJAX**

you could retrieve your display_data_hash using AJAX (jQuery here) like:

```
$.getJSON('/yourcontroller/youraction.json', function(data) {

   display(data);

});
```

and in your controller you render a json response like:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def your_display_action

      @my_data = .....

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{ render :json => @my_data }
      end
   end
end
```

**Second Approach without AJAX**

If you don't want to fire an AJAX request you could do something like:

In your layout view add a section:

```
<html>
<head>
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= yield :inline_js %>
</script>
....
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

then create a helper method like:

```
def insert_display_data(display_data) {

  # convert hash to json
  data_json = display_data.to_json

  content_for :inline_js do
     "display('#{data_json}');"
  end
}
```

and in your display JavaScript function do:

```
function display(data) {

  if(data instanceof String) { 
     // parse JSON using jquery
     data = $.parseJSON(data);
  }

  // your code...
}
```

Comment: thanks sled.  why do i need to make a AJAX call?  when i call my display controller, it should return html and javascript, i just want server to populate my display_data_hash in my javascript.

Comment: hi, then go for the second solution using content_for and a helper function :)

Comment: thanks for the code, it's helpful.  i guess there is no way to update javascript dynamically without involving html, the only solution is to modify the content of <script> tag in html.

Comment: that's perfectly fine if you do it in a clean way. The problem is that the syntax of a ruby hash and a javascript hash are different. Therefore you can pass your hash as json and parse it in your JS function to a javascript hash. You have to put your data hash somewhere in your html code otherwise it won't reach the client :)